# Proof of identity presented in Equation 5 from "Exact and Approximate Construction of Digital Phase Modulations by Superposition of AMP"

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

In P. A. Laurent "Exact and Approximate Construction of Digital Phase Modulations by Superposition of AMP" 1986, a mathematic identity is presented in the 5-th equation without proof as it was something easy to verify. Well, I try to verify it with no success. Please any one can show me where this come from?

**Preliminary Definitions Presented in the Paper**

$\varphi(t)$ is an arbitrary continous function that is equal to $0$ for $t \leq 0$ and is equal to $\Phi$ for $t\geq LT$, where $\Phi$ is a positive constant smaller than $\pi$.
$$ \varphi(t) = 0 \quad t \leq 0$$
$$ \varphi(t) = \Phi \quad t \geq LT $$
$$ a_n \in \left \{  +1, -1 \right \} $$
$$ t = NT + \tau \quad 0 \leq \tau < T$$
$$ C = \cos \Phi \quad S=\sin \Phi \quad J=\exp{j\Phi}$$

**The Identity**

"The next (and most important) step consists in replacing the complex exponential associated to the nth bit by an equivalent sum of two terms" (P.A. Laurent, 1986).

$$ \exp j\left[ a_n \cdot \varphi(t-NT)\right] = 
\frac{ \sin \left[ \Phi - \varphi(t-nT) \right]}{S} + 
J^{a_n} \frac{ \sin \left[ \varphi(t-nT)\right]}{S}$$

Answer (score 1):

I am also reading Laurent's paper recently. The left hand side is
$\exp[ja_{n}\varphi(t-nT)]=\cos[a_n\varphi(t-nT)]+j\sin[a_n\varphi(t-nt)]=\cos[\varphi(t-nT)]+j(-1)^{\frac{1-a_n}{2}}\sin[\varphi(t-nT)]$

The last step is due to $a_n \in \left \{  +1, -1 \right \}$.

$J^{a_n}=\exp(j\Phi a_n)=\cos(\Phi a_n)+j\sin(\Phi a_n)=\cos(\Phi)+j(-1)^{\frac{1-a_n}{2}}\sin(\Phi)$

The first term of the right hand side is
$\frac{\sin(\Phi)\cos[\varphi(t-nT)]-\cos(\Phi)\sin[\varphi(t-nT)]}{\sin(\Phi)}=\cos[\varphi(t-nT)]-\cot(\Phi)\sin[\varphi(t-nT)]$

The second term of the right hand side is
$[\cos(\Phi)+j(-1)^{\frac{1-a_n}{2}}\sin(\Phi)]\frac{ \sin \left[ \varphi(t-nT)\right]}{\sin(\Phi)}=\cot(\Phi)\sin[\varphi(t-nT)]+j(-1)^{\frac{1-a_n}{2}}\sin[\varphi(t-nT)]$

So the right hand side of EQ(5) is $\cos[\varphi(t-nT)]+j(-1)^{\frac{1-a_n}{2}}\sin[\varphi(t-nT)]$ which is the same as the left hand side.

The proof is not hard. However it is unclear how Laurent got it in the first place. I hope someone will explain the intuition behind EQ(5) in the future.